# How to get actual language in a WinRT app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to get the actual language of the OS like on Windows Phone? I'm using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterIsoString`, but I recieve always en and not the right language, which is `de` in my case.

So how can I get the actual language in a WinRT app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
Windows.Globalization.Language.CurrentInputMethodLanguageTag
```

to get the actual language. It returns for example de-DE, if you are using a german verison of Windows 8.

Comment: Actually, that returns the current keyboard language, not the user Regional Settings selection! WinRT doesn't have a direct equivalent to CurrentCulture, but `Windows.Globalization` namespace does provide alternatives to it!

Comment: My keyboard layout does not reflect my preferred language. This is common when you belong to a local minority (as actually the majority of the people of the world do), and when you prefer English as the system language because you interact internationally.

Answer (score 26):

There are actually many "kind-of wrong" answers to this.

- `Windows.Globalization.Language.CurrentInputMethodLanguageTag` as pointed out by Thomas will not work in all the scenarios. It only returns the language in which user's keyboard is displayed.
- You can also use `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages` but it is a combination of user language preference and applications supported languages.

For most acurate user preference language, You'll need to use `Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]`.

Comment: I'll use "Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]" for now.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN the correct answer is:

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]
```

This should be user's most preferred language.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationPreferences.PreferredLanguage
```

Comment: That doesn't exists on UWP :(

Answer (score 1):

If you create a HTML5/javascript Windows App. You can use this:

```
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
alert(language);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String topUserLanguage = GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0];
Windows.Globalization.Language userLanguage = new Windows.Globalization.Language(topUserLanguage);

if (userLanguage.Script.Equals("Arab") || userLanguage.Script.Equals("Hebr"))
{
....................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Community Toolkit now offers an easy API for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.helpers.systeminformation.culture?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable#Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_Helpers_SystemInformation_Culture

Usage:

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Helpers;


var cultureInfo = SystemInformation.Instance.Culture;
```

Sample code: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/c40264008e596b23e7342dd15fdb0e3f2551a699/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/SystemInformation/SystemInformationPage.xaml.cs#L25