# Winjs get system language with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, winjs

Is it possible to get the system language in my app programmatically?
My app is written in HTML/JavaScript.

In chrome it's possible to use the code "navigator.language" to get the browser's language.
I want to do this with my Windows 8 app.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer:

```
Windows.Globalization.Language.currentInputMethodLanguageTag
```

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799619/how-to-get-actual-language-in-a-winrt-app

Comment: A clarification: things are not as straightforward as checking the WinRT property above, although that's probably the best method available. For instance, if I have Finnish as the display language but haven't downloaded the language pack (= I see the OS in en-US), this API returns "fi". OS also roams the user settings between machines, so if I use one machine in Finnish (have downloaded the lang pack etc), and one machine in English, the selection and the value API returns might be "fi" on both machines even though I see (and want to see) one machine in en-US (because my selection was sync'd).